# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $f(X)=a_0+a_1X+...+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+X^n \in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a monic polynomial.
> Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ be a root of $f$ and the set $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]=\left\lbrace g(\alpha) \mid g\in \mathbb{Z}[X]\right\rbrace$ is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$.
> Let $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ a prime number.
>
> Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(p)$.

Since $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(p) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p[X]$, is the same to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha]$.

I have defined an epimorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[X]\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha]$ given by $\phi(g(X))=g(\alpha)\pmod p$ so the goal is to see if $\ker\phi = (f)$ and apply the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Since $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, then $f$ is in the kernel. Hence $(f) \subseteq \ker\phi$.

But I am in troubles proving the other content:

Let $g\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be in the kernel. By the Division Algorithm for Polynomials we have $g=qf+r$ where either $r=0$ or $\deg(r)<\deg(f)$.

Applying $\phi$, we have that $r(\alpha)=0$. Then all coefficients of $r$ are  $\overline{0}$, but it doesn't imply necessarily $r(x)=0$.

If $r(x)=0$, then $g(x)=q(x)f(x) \in (f)$ and therefore, $\ker\phi\subseteq (f)$. How can I justify that $r(x)=0$? Or is there another way to prove the content?

Comment: Where does $p$ enter the picture?

Comment: Also, $p\in\ker(\phi)$, but $p\not\in (f)$

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to prove that $$\Bbb Z_p[X]/(f)\cong \Bbb Z[\alpha]/(p)$$?

Comment: I think you are trying to prove $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha]$. If then consider the evaluation map at $\alpha$.

Comment: If  $f=x$ the quotient ring will be $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f) = \mathbb{Z}$ so you can't prove this as stated. @cansomeonehelpmeout seems correct in suggesting you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, so should I define another $\phi$? Is the second part of the proof incorrect? Or perhaps the initial statement to be proved is incorrect and I should be asked to prove the isomorphism that you say?

Comment: I read now the comment of @CyclotomicField. Maybe the statement of the exercise in my notes is incorrect. Because is denoted $\overline{f}$ as the polynomial $f$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Then is probably that the thing that I have to prove is $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(\overline{f})\cong\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(p)$, that is the same that all of you say, is not?

Comment: @Claudia note that $x$ has all of its coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for all $p$. The same counter-example works.

Comment: @CyclotomicField OK, so if we consider that I am asked to prove $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(\overline{f})\cong \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(p) $, is the same that prove $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]/(f)\cong\mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha]$. Then, if we consider the map $\phi$ defined in the question and the reasonings, then I have that $r(x)=0$ and the isomorphism is proved.